# "warning: multiple values for a block parameter (2 for 1)" in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a function users_by_role

and it returns data in following format,

```
[
  [#<Role id: 1, name: "Developer">,[#<User id:1, name: "Abc">,#<User id:2, name: "xyz">]]
  [#<Role id: 2, name: "Tester">,[#<User id:11, name: "Abcd">,#<User id:12, name: "wxyz">]]
]
```

Now, I want to select users for given Role/s

I am using,

```
project.users_by_role.select{|o| o.first.name == "Developer"}
```

where project is a Project object

All good, code returns me the data but along with which I get following warning

> warning: multiple values for a block parameter (2 for 1)

Also I am looking for optimized and shorter way of doing this

Complete code snippet looks like:

```
project.users_by_role.select{|o| o.first.name == "Developer" }.collect{|e| e.last.map{|f| [f.id,f.firstname + ' ' + f.lastname]}}.flatten(1).uniq
```

By above code I want to get all the user names for a given role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The warning:** it says that you expected 1 argt, and it passes 2.
That's because it "expands the argts" to take account of the 2 elements array.

```
project.users_by_role.select {|role, users| role.name == "Developer"}
```

**And for a better way:**

If the role is uniq within the #users_by_role data returned, you can avoid a map.

```
users = project.users_by_role.select {|role, users| role.name == "Developer"}.first.last
users_for_select = users.map {|user| [user.id, "#{user.firstname} #{user.lastname}"] }
```

Comment: looks like i misunderstood the data returned by users_by_role. yes it should be project.users_by_role.select {|role, users|}

Comment: and regarding second answer, project.users_by_role.select {|role, users| role.name == "Developer" or role.name == Tester"}.first.last. wont give desired result. so this is what i am using,  project.users_by_role.select {|role, users| role.name == "Developer" or role.name == "Reporter"}.collect{|role,users| users.map{|u| [u.id,u.firstname]}}.flatten(1).uniq

Comment: many thnx for figuring out the mistake. also would you like to comment on better way?

Comment: I assumed you wanted to retrieve only one role, so your way is fine.